# Como Trabalhar com Grunt

Tags: javascript, html, css, grunt

Tenho lido bastante sobre algumas ferramentas usadas para facilitar o workflow no front-end e conheci o Grunt, entendi qual a função dele e quando ele pode ser útil, porém tenho a seguinte dúvida, quando eu usar o Grunt para realizar as tarefas de minificação, concatenação, etc, onde devo salvar os novos arquivos? Minha dúvida se dá pelo fato de que achei estranho a ideia de criar um diretório com os mesmos arquivos do diretório original só que minificados.
Para resumir, em um site no diretório `site-teste/` qual a estrutura correta seria algo parecido com isso?

`| site-teste/
| --img/
| --js/
| --css/
| --depois-do-Grunt/
| ----img/
| ----js/
| ----css/
| ----index.html
| --index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade não é necessário que você crie um diretório para cada ação do grunt.

Você pode salvar os arquivos minificados dentro do mesmo diretório. Para identificação, evitar que o arquivo seja substituído e por boa prática adiciona-se ao final do nome do arquivo algo como `*.min.js` ou `*.min.css`. Isso identifica os arquivos minificados.

Você também pode, configurar o grunt para ter uma pasta de desenvolvimento dos arquivos e outra pasta com os arquivos para o ambiente de produção. Criando algo semelhante ao scaffolding abaixo.

```
Gruntfile.js
dev-assets\
public\
   |  -  css\
   |  -  javascript\
   |  -  images\
```

Assim você pode desenvolver os arquivos em uma pasta e o Grunt alimenta as pastas de que irão para a produção, com os arquivos já minificados.

Para usar o exemplo acima, você só precisa configurar o seu `Gruntfile.js` com os parâmetros indicando a pasta onde estão os arquivos e a pasta que deve ser armazenada as versões minificadas. Exemplo abaixo com o `uglify` do Grunt

```js
uglify : {
    options: {
        banner: '/* Minify Javascript Version */'
    },
    js : {
        src : './dev-assets/file.js',
        dest : './public/javascript/scripts.min.js'
    }
}
```

Com esse trecho ele pega o file na pasta de desenvolvimento e minifica ela na pasta public de produção. Você pode consultar os plugins para fazer ainda mais.

Comment: Eu sabia que podia salvar onde quisesse, só queria saber qual o jeito mais indicado, que pelo que vi na sua resposta é criar uma pasta com os assets minificados ou concatenados, etc, certo? Isso para uma melhorar organização e maior produtividade, entendi direito??

Comment: Exato, cada um escolhe o melhor jeito de trabalhar. Eu prefiro criar uma pasta de desenvolvimento, onde mantenho os assets sem a minificação. Como o Grunt é um task runner, você pode criar um automatizador de deploy que seleciona só a pasta com os assets já prontos, ou só pega a pasta public e colocar no servidor se for o caso. Vai do seu gosto.